# How to use Tooling API to get available values from picklist

Tags: soql, query, custom-field, tooling-api

How would one get the values available values of a System Custom Field?

Here are the details of the "System Custom Field":

Field Label: "Working Status"

Field Name: "Working_Status"

API Name: Working_Status__c

Object Name: "System"

Data Type: "Picklist"

Values: { "Running", "Starting Up", "Unknown"}

I am using the following query:

`SELECT Values FROM CustomField WHERE ObjectName = 'System.Working_Status__c'`

However, this is not working.  I can use the describe the Lightning Platform REST API describe method of doing this, but it returns every possibility in the system.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_describe.htm

What do I need to change in my SOQL query to make this happen?

Answer (score 4):

It's worth noting you don't need any API calls at all to get this information, and can simply use the field describe (which is also accessible via REST API).

```
List<PicklistEntry> entries = System.Working_Status__c.getDescribe().getPicklistValues();

List<String> values = new List<String>();
for (PicklistEntry entry : entries)
{
    values.add(entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: The source code you listed does not work, needed to modify it to:

Comment: ```List<String> lstPickvals=new List<String>();
Schema.SObjectType tarType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('System__c');
Sobject Object_name = tarType.newSObject();
Schema.sObjectType sobject_type = Object_name.getSObjectType();
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sobject_describe = sobject_type.getDescribe();
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> field_map = sobject_describe.fields.getMap();
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> pick_list_values = field_map.get('Working_Status__c').getDescribe().getPickListValues();
for (Schema.PicklistEntry a : pick_list_values) {
    lstPickvals.add(a.getValue());
}```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do that using tooling API. You have to specify the ObjectName and FieldName.

If you check metadata for CustomField ObjectName is called as **TableEnumOrId**
and FieldName is called as **DeveloperName**.

The picklist values/valueset are stored in a field called as "**Metadata**".

So your SOQL will be.

```
SELECT Id,NameSpacePrefix, DeveloperName, TableEnumOrId,Metadata FROM CustomField WHERE TableEnumOrId = 'Account' and DeveloperName='License_Type'
```

When I tried it in workbench it returns the picklist valueset.

Note: Developer Console doesn't support the return of complex return type so you have to view this in Workbench or any other rest client.

*As pointed by @Sfdcfox, When you query metadata you can query a single field at a time.

[image]

Comment: You may want to mention that you can only query one field at a time when using Metadata.

Comment: Getting error:

```"message": "\nDeveloperName,TableEnumOrId,Metadata FROM CustomField WHERE TableEnumOrId\n                                          ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:69\nsObject type 'CustomField' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.",```

Comment: How are you querring? Are you using tooling API? CustomField isn't supported in other API's.

Comment: I'm using cURL to do a HTTP GET: ```https://inst.salesforce.com/services/data/v42.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id,NameSpacePrefix,DeveloperName,TableEnumOrId,Metadata+FROM+CustomField+WHERE+TableEnumOrId+=+%27System%27+and+DeveloperName=%27Working_Status%27```

Comment: Thats URL is normal query URL and not the tooling API query URL.

The tooling API querry url is: `https://inst.salesforce.com/services/data/v41.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+Id,NameSpacePrefix,DeveloperName,TableEnumOrId,Metadata+FROM+CustomField+WHERE+TableEnumOrId+=+%27System%27+and+DeveloperName=%27Working_Status%27`